# Spring Data + @Query(JPQL) + join fetch + QueryDSL Predicate

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, jpql, querydsl

I have query method in Repository interface:

```
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Student> {

    @Query("select s from Student s join fetch s.subjects join fetch s.teachers where s.firstName = ?1 and s.secondName = ?2")
    List<Student> findStudents(String firstName, String secondName)

}
```

Works fine!

But how can i use QueryDSL Predicate instead of parameters?

```
@Query("select s from Student s join fetch s.subjects join fetch s.teachers where s.firstName = ?1 and s.secondName = ?2")
List<Student> findStudents(Predicate predicate)
```

Thanks a lot for your ideas!

Comment: What would be the point of passing a Predicate, since your actual query needs only two well-known parameters?

Comment: Marc Tarin. I am looking for a similar thing. I want to define a custom Query AND use my predicates which i parse in with the annothion in my controller. Do you know if that is possible?